# one table matching multiple row

Tags: mysql

i have "answer" table , I will keep many users answer.
i want to make mysql query matching

```
questionid = questionid AND
answerid  = answerid AND
profileid != profileid ($_SESION['profileid'])
```

how can i do?

table look like ;

```
profileid |  questionid | answerid
25           1            3
25           2            1
25           3            2
36           1            3
28           2            2
19           2            1
19           3            2
```

Comment: What your asking exactly?What's your are excepted output?kindly mention that.

Comment: Can you show the answer table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like same question and answer pattern for other profiles, in that case the below query can be used.

```
SELECT a.*,b.profileid FROM question a JOIN question b 
ON(a.questionid = b.questionid AND a.answerid  = b.answerid AND a.profileid != b.profileid)
WHERE a.profileid=25;
```

Comment: This query is work .Thank you for fast and true answer .